# Reporting results from glmmadmb

Tags: r

I am very new to R and I want to know if random effects in the different areas where my research took place could be biasing my results, and providing a false positive effect on my conditions. My data is based on natural observations taking place in four different conditions, over 9 areas. It is a between subjects design- each row is an observation of a different subject.

Condition =factor (4 levels)

Area = random effect (9 levels)

GeneralDisplayingBehaviours = DV

ObsTime = How many minuets the observations took place for

This is what my model looks like

```
data2$Condition<-as.factor(data2$Condition)
data2$Area<-as.factor(data2$Area)
data2$Condition<-relevel(data2$Condition,ref="22")
data2$Area<-relevel(data2$Area,ref="1")

mod<-glmmadmb(GeneralDisplayingBehaviours~Condition+ObsTime+(1|Area), data=data2, family="nbinom", zeroInflation=TRUE)
```

This is the out put:

```
Call:
glmmadmb(formula = GeneralDisplayingBehaviours ~ Condition +
ObsTime + (1 | Area), data = data2, family = "nbinom", zeroInflation = TRUE)

AIC: 2990.1 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)  
(Intercept)   1.6233     0.5019    3.23   0.0012 ** 
Condition12   1.3291     0.1330    9.99   <2e-16 ***
Condition11   1.2965     0.1294   10.02   <2e-16 ***
Condition21   0.0715     0.1351    0.53   0.5966    
ObsTime       0.0829     0.0341    2.43   0.0151 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Number of observations: total=360, Area=9 
Random effect variance(s):
Group=Area

             Variance    StdDev
(Intercept) 8.901e-09 9.434e-05

Negative binomial dispersion parameter: 1.7376 (std. err.: 0.16112)
Zero-inflation: 0.16855  (std. err.:  0.02051 )

Log-likelihood: -1487.06
```

I would then go on to change the condition ref for each level, and I think I would have to do the same with area.

How would I interpret these results and report them?
What does this tell me about my random effect of area? Does it impact the DV?
Are the conditions significantly different in terms of the DV, and which conditions are significantly different for which?

For the last question I have a feeling I would need to do multiple comparisons so how would I do this in GLMMABMD?

Thank you

Comment: this would probably be better for `r-sig-mixed-models@r-project.org` or [CrossValidated](http://stats.stackexchange.com);  only the very last is a programming question.

Comment: Oh sorry, I  got confused with all the different ones.